# How do I update WebBrowser for my C# Application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, google-maps, webbrowser-control

When I try to Open google map in my C# Application, I get this error:

> You seem to be using an unsupported browser. Old browsers can put your
>   security at risk, are slow and don't work with newer Google Maps
>   features. To access Google Maps, you'll need to update to a modern
>   browser.

How can I upgrade my Browser there or How to get rid of this error?